# CLIon - can't get visual studio toolchain to work: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, clion

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.1.3/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/dbak/Projects/firmware/testing/cmake-build-release-visual-studio/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_99064\fast 
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_99064.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe @C:\Users\dbak\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9D03.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_99064.exe
        "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\dbak\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9E1D.tmp
    LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_99064.exe /implib:cmTC_99064.lib /pdb:C:\Users\dbak\Projects\firmware\testing\cmake-build-release-visual-studio\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_99064.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_99064.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
```

However, MSVCRTD.lib is located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64". So I do not know what I can possibly do. Is this some issue with Clion not having that location in path?

Comment: What are your CLion **Toolchain** settings?

Comment: x86_arm, uwp
Cmake: bundled

That's all.

Comment: Try changing your to 64-bit toolchain. CLion appears to be looking for the Visual Studio x64 compiler libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change architecture to `x86`?
[Where to find architecture setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0OL5.png)